# How can I disable the game to count for more than one for each object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using C# with Unity and trying to practice [this example](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/)
I want the game to count when the ball collide each cube for once only, but it seems the ball count for the same cube whenever it find a collide between them, so how can I make an object in an object in a prefab disabled to be changed but still visible ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Text countText;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start ()
    {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
        {
            // How it can know which one of the object in the prefab that tagged to "Pick Up" is selected ? and how can make it disabled to be effected by the ball in the second time after the collide ?
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText ();
        }
    }

    void SetCountText ()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want `OnTriggerEnter()` or `OnCollisionEnter()`? Make a script in your cube and add a `OnCollisionEnter()` where it changes tag or something when collision with the ball is detected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you destroy the "other" collider, then it can't collide again. Or you can disable it, if you prefer, but it would mean the same thing.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
        {
            // How it can know which one of the object in the prefab that tagged to "Pick Up" is selected ? and how can make it disabled to be effected by the ball in the second time after the collide ?
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText ();
            Destroy(other); // Add this...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have a couple of alternatives. One of them is:

**CUBE object**

- set a `boolean` variable on your cubes. `boolean hasBeenHit` or similar. This starts att `false`.
- Give the cube a `OnTriggerEnter()` where it sets the `hasBeenHit = true`.
- Make a public getter for `hasBeenHit`.

**Ball object**

- In `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` check if `other` is a cube.
- If it is a cube, check if its `hasBeenHit` is `true` or `false`.
- If it is `false`, increment `count`